# Calling upon data in just 1 cell from sqlite in python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

My question is essentially twofold. Firstly, I have a database using SQlite, which I'm running with Python.

My database is:

```
CREATE TABLE cards (id integer primary key autoincrement not null, ref text unique
check(ref!=''), name text, description text, quantity integer default 0, cat1 text,
cat2 text);

INSERT INTO "cards" VALUES(1,'lx247','green door',NULL,20,'abstract','');
INSERT INTO "cards" VALUES(2,'lxx247','green door',NULL,20,'abstract','');
INSERT INTO "cards" VALUES(3,'lxx2f47','green door',NULL,20,'abstract','');
```

And I'm running the following python code:

```
import sqlite3 as lite
import sys
con = lite.connect('cards.db')
idn = raw_input("Enter your ID number")
with con:
    cur=con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT quantity FROM cards WHERE ref=?", idn)  
    print "Quantity" + str(cur.fetchone())
```

Firstly, when I execute this script, and enter 'lx247' into the prompt, I get the following error message:

```
Enter your ID numberlx247
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 7, in <module>
    cur.execute("SELECT quantity FROM cards WHERE ref=?", idn)  
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. 
The current statement uses 1, and there are 5 supplied.
```

I've identified that the 5 it refers to are the number of characters in what I enter into the idn input (lx247). If I change the line:

```
cur.execute("SELECT quantity FROM cards WHERE ref=?", idn)
```

to

```
cur.execute("SELECT quantity FROM cards WHERE id=?", idn)
```

and enter '2' at the prompt, it returns:

```
Enter your ID number2
Quantity(20,)
```

So this has told me there is something wrong with the way it is handling the idn parameter to look up the ref column. So my first question is **how do I get it to look up the value I enter in idn in column ref**?

The second question is how do I then get it to output the value as a number, rather than in the form (20,), because I then want to later direct python to add or subtract another number, x, to it and update the entry in the database to 20+x, so I'm looking to create a variable in python that is the value of the quantity column for a certain ref entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass in a *sequence* of parameters, make it a tuple with one element:

```
cur.execute("SELECT quantity FROM cards WHERE ref=?", (idn,))
```

Python strings are sequences too, so if `idn` is a 5-character string, python sees a sequence of length 5.

The database always returns *rows* of columns, even for results with only one column. A row is essentially a Python tuple, a sequence. It's the same problem as your `idn` parameter, but in reverse. Take the one column out of the result row by indexing:

```
print "Quantity " + str(cur.fetchone()[0])
```

A quick demo with your sample database:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> con = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
>>> con.executescript('''\
... CREATE TABLE cards (id integer primary key autoincrement not null, ref text unique
... check(ref!=''), name text, description text, quantity integer default 0, cat1 text,
... cat2 text);
... 
... INSERT INTO "cards" VALUES(1,'lx247','green door',NULL,20,'abstract','');
... INSERT INTO "cards" VALUES(2,'lxx247','green door',NULL,20,'abstract','');
... INSERT INTO "cards" VALUES(3,'lxx2f47','green door',NULL,20,'abstract','');
... ''')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x10ad66ab0>
>>> idn = 'lx247'
>>> cur=con.cursor()
>>> cur.execute("SELECT quantity FROM cards WHERE ref=?", (idn,))
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x10ad66b20>
>>> print "Quantity " + str(cur.fetchone()[0])
Quantity 20
```

Comment: Wow, that was a quick reply! Thank you, it worked an absolute charm.